# Bluetooth LE start advertising with service data in iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

On my Xamarin app, I start a GATT server with an advertise that include service data. This works fine on Android and I can read the data from the clients (Android and iOS) during the scan. This is the piece of code that do the job (bytes contains my data value):

```
var data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .SetIncludeDeviceName(false)
                .AddServiceData(new Android.OS.ParcelUuid(Java.Util.UUID.FromString(SecurityUuid.Service)), bytes)
                .Build();

            Advertiser.StartAdvertising(settings, data, AdvertiseCallbacks);
```

I'm implementing now this part on iOS but I cannot figure out how to include the service data. The only way I found is to add a new characteristic where store the value but that not fit my needs because I need to read that value without connect to the service but simply during the scan.

Here the code where I start the advertising on iOS:

```
var data = new NSDictionary(
                new NSString(SecurityUuid.Service),
                NSObject.FromObject(value));

            var advertisingData = new NSDictionary(
                CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey,
                new NSString("test"),
                CBAdvertisement.DataServiceUUIDsKey,
                NSObject.FromObject(arry),
                CBAdvertisement.DataServiceDataKey,
                data
                );


            _peripheralManager.StartAdvertising(advertisingData);
```

The official documentation of Apple says that I can use just CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey and CBAdvertisement.DataServiceUUIDsKey starting an advertisement. I try to add the CBAdvertisement.DataServiceDataKey value (because from the client I read this to get the value been set from Android advertisement) but it doesn't work.

Any advise?

Comment: Hi , whether this is a pure Xamarin iOS project ?

Comment: It's a cross-platform project but the bluetooth part is native in each platform